# SQL Where clause to return records within 30 day time span of joined table dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi all I have an SQL question. I have a table I have created which I want to use joined in my query.

Example below (which I have created so as not to share the original data). The where statement I believe is going to be the important part which I need help with.

ALL - Contains the data in the database including dates.

WEB (below)- Table I have added

```
DATE        ID       ORDER NUMBER
21/06/2016  RED      11148
22/06/2016  BLUE     16996
23/06/2016  RED      11000
24/06/2016  GREEN    17783
25/06/2016  RED      12487
26/06/2016  BLUE     12837
27/06/2016  RED      11755
28/06/2016  GREEN    11698
```

My query start is this:

```
SELECT
I.DATE,
I.ORDER_NUMBER,
I.ID,
I.FLOW,
I.MEDIUM,
I.REASON,
I.SUB_REASON 

FROM WEB D
JOIN ALL I
ON D.ORDER_NUMBER = I.ORDER_NUMBER
```

What I need is a WHERE statement to produce the following - I would like to pull back everything from within ALL which is plus 30 days from each DATE in WEB.

So to clarify if

```
DATE        ID       ORDER NUMBER
21/06/2016  RED      11148
```

exists in WEB I want to pull all the matching ORDER_NUMBER from ALL which happened within the 30 days post 21/06/2016 (the date held in WEB).

So the output would look something like this. As you can see the date returned is within 30 days post the date in the table which is joined.

```
DATE       ORDER_NUMBER    ID     FLOW     MEDIUM     REASON     SUB_REASON
26/06/2016 11148           RED    IN       WEB        IN         ONLINE
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify, provide sample data for `ALL` and the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
`WHERE i.DATE BETWEEN d.DATE AND d.DATE+30`
In abstracting your real data you have overlooked that date is a reserved word so every occurrence need double quotes round e.g.
`WHERE i."DATE" BETWEEN d."DATE" AND d."DATE"+30`

Comment: I think this might be what I'm after only issue is both my data sets are quite large so it might be overloading it a bit. If I can get it to export for me then I will mark as answered. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use BETWEEN with sysdate and sysdate-30, something like following

```
SELECT
  I.DATE,
  I.ORDER_NUMBER,
  I.ID,
  I.FLOW,
  I.MEDIUM,
  I.REASON,
  I.SUB_REASON 
FROM WEB D
  JOIN ALL I ON D.ORDER_NUMBER = I.ORDER_NUMBER
WHERE I.DATE BETWEEN sysdate-30 and sysdate
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. How would that sit on the end of my query (I'm pretty novice at this) will that match against the WEB table though or just bring back everything?

Comment: Do you have any other conditions in where clause if not use this edited query